# Regular expression, find all words between two delimiters

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex to match the following:

**String**: "Hello #world it is #party time#"
**Matches**: "world", and "party time"

While playing around with regexes I can only match one or the other but never both. Is this even possible?

Comment: What programming language?  `world` is not surrounded by the delimiters...

Comment: What are some of your attempts? Also, did you mean `#world#` in your string?

Comment: Language I'm using is PHP. Because we don't use content editable divs we use an extra # as a stopgap solution to match tags with spaces. Matching the first one is easy, this is what I have for the one with spaces; http://regex101.com/r/jQ6cN6

Comment: Have you tried paying with an online regex elavuator such as http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?  I found it indispensible for learning

Comment: There is ambiguity with using # as a "stop gap" vs. wanting to match both non-spaced words and spaced words.  You must either pick a different closing delimiter or use the stop gap no matter what

Comment: Why can't you use two regexes?

Comment: @CanSpice, I can but I was just wondering if there was a single regex I could use instead that would match both instances.

Comment: Using one regex to do the job of two usually means at least three times the headaches. Split them up and save yourself the headaches.

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution for this, with the way you have it setup right now. There is ambiguity with using # as a "stop gap" vs. wanting to match both non-spaced words and spaced words. The problem is the space..it is both a valid character AND non-valid character, depending on the value, and there's no other way to tell which is which.

You can't break it down into multiple regexes.  If you first try to do like `#([^#]+)` it will match `#world` and `#party`.  If you instead try to first do `#([^#]+)#` it will match `world it is`. Even if you throw a negative lookbehind into the mix `#((?:(?<!\b).)+)#` you will match `world it is #party time`

To solve for this, you must do either

1. Put the # closing delimiter (the "stop gap" as you call it) at the end of *all* phrases, even the single words.  Then you can do `#([^#]+)#`
2. change the spaces in the phrases to something else (like an
   underscore). Then you can do `#([^\b]+)` (well this may vary depending on what you'd swap the space for)